# Scale up Dask-SSH Cluster

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing, scale, dask

I managed to create an Dask SSH Cuda Cluster using the following:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, SSHCluster
cluster = SSHCluster(
        ["localhost", "192.168.1.119", "192.168.1.191"],
        connect_options={"known_hosts": None,"username": "vinhdiesal"},
        worker_options={"nthreads": 40},
        scheduler_options={"port": 0, "dashboard_address": ":8797"},
        worker_module='dask_cuda.dask_cuda_worker')
```

It results in the 4 workers as follows:

```
dask
+---------------------------+---------+
|                           | version |
+---------------------------+---------+
| client                    | 2.11.0  |
| scheduler                 | 2.11.0  |
| tcp://192.168.1.119:38425 | 2.11.0  |
| tcp://192.168.1.119:41579 | 2.11.0  |
| tcp://192.168.1.191:45641 | 2.17.2  |
| tcp://192.168.1.191:46713 | 2.17.2  |
+---------------------------+---------+
```

Is there a way to scale up so I can get more dask workers?
I was able to increase the threads, but I wanted to scale the amount of workers.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the workers to start multiple processes by passing an `nprocs` argument:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, SSHCluster
cluster = SSHCluster(
        ["localhost", "192.168.1.119", "192.168.1.191"],
        connect_options={"known_hosts": None,"username": "vinhdiesal"},
        worker_options={"nthreads": 16, "nprocs": 4},
        scheduler_options={"port": 0, "dashboard_address": ":8797"},
        worker_module='dask_cuda.dask_cuda_worker')
```

Comment: can you pass different parameters to the different worker nodes (nthreads / nprocs) ? say 8 threads and 2 procs for the IP ending in 119 and 16 threads and 4 procs for the IP ending in 191? also would calling cluster.scale(4) have the same effect as passing "nprocs" as 4?